# How to validate inner partialviews in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have logon view which contains forgotpasword link. It will open a new partialview on main view(Logon) itself.

On submission of forgotpassword view, validation fires for both the views.

I want to validate inner partialview(forgotpassword) when click forgotpassword submit but not the main Logon view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Would be good if you could show us your code. Right now it's only a guess that you have both views in one form, so that's what is causing validation on both views. Document your question and you will get better more precise answers :)